# ROS Lunar version conflict with Ubuntu 16.04LTS - libcollida-dom2

Tags: ros-lunar, ubuntu, ubuntu-xenial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As with each new ROS release, there are install conflicts. The system on which the install was done was running Ubuntu 16.04LTS, updated with the latest Ubuntu updates before ROS install was attempted.  Previous versions of ROS had been removed.

During ROS install, Ubuntu reported a system problem:

```
Package: libcollida-dom2.4-do0 2.4.4+ds1-1.
collida-dom

"An Ubuntu package has a file conflict with a package that is not a genuine Ubuntu package".
```

At the end of the ROS install, that install reported.

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libcollada-dom2.4-dp0_2.4.4+ds1-1_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libcollada-dom2.4-dp-dev_2.4.4+ds1-1_amd64.deb
```

This looks a lot like the problem reported here, in 2015:

http://answers.ros.org/question/222892/collada-dom24-sp-dev-causes-dist-upgrade-to-fail-on-ubuntu-1404/

But that bug was in ROS-Indigo for Ubuntu 14.04. It was fixed there. Looks like it's been broken again.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/262813/ros-lunar-version-conflict-with-ubuntu-16.04lts---libcollida-dom2/) by [John Nagle](https://answers.ros.org/users/2519/john-nagle/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2017-05-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [John Nagle](https://answers.ros.org/users/2519/john-nagle/) on 2017-05-30**:
If I then run Ubuntu's software updater, it wants to update Collida-dom to 2.4.0.  So the ROS and Ubuntu updaters are now fighting.

**Comment by [John Nagle](https://answers.ros.org/users/2519/john-nagle/) on 2017-05-31**:
See also https://github.com/ros/robot_model/issues/118 where this was fixed in 2015. Now it's broken again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Reported as a bug at https://github.com/ros/robot_model/issues/203

---

Originally posted by [John Nagle](https://answers.ros.org/users/2519/john-nagle/) with karma: 41 on 2017-05-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0